recursive components in angular ng303
I have two components, that reference each other in some manner. Here is an simplified example.
@Component({
  selector: 'a',
  template: ` elements: <b /> `,
})
export class a {}

@Component({
  selector: 'b',
  template: `
    @switch (type) {
      @case (a) {
        <a />
      }
      @case (c) {
        <c />
      }
    }
  `,
})
export class b {}

I get an NG303 (cyclic imports) error here. And I totally understand why.
But how can I solve such an issue?

Normal patterns for resolving such things like implementing interfaces won't work here, as it's template code not typescript.
Using Ivy Full build which would solve the issue is also no option.


please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated

You could create a common module and import this module to the parent of these components, so that you will be able to get rid of the error. But note my example will give maximum call stack error due to infinite recursion.
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { a, c } from './comps';

@Component({
  selector: 'b',
  template: `
    @switch (type) {
      @case ('a') {
        <a></a>
      }
      @case ('c') {
        <c></c>
      }
    }
  `,
})
export class b {
  type = 'a';
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [a, b, c],
  exports: [a, b, c],
})
export class SomeModule {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [SomeModule],
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <b></b>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
